# System Oracle -> Oracle Managed

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net, odp.net-managed

I swapped out the references but I am getting an error that it can't cast System.Oracle to Oracle.ManagedDataAccess

```
public static DataSet ExecuteDataSetWithTimeOut(string spName, object[] parameterValues)
{
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(); 

    cmd.CommandTimeout = 7200;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = spName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("o_msg", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 300).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("o_shipper_inv", OracleDbType.RefCursor).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("i_start_dt", OracleDbType.Date).Value = parameterValues[2].ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("i_end_dt", OracleDbType.Date).Value = parameterValues[3].ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("i_user_id", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = parameterValues[4].ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("i_facility_cd", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = null;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("i_shipper_cd", OracleDbType.Varchar2).Value = null;
    return Db.ExecuteDataSet(cmd);
}
```

Comment: Did you also change ´usimg´ from ´System.Oracle´ to ´Oracle.ManagedDataAccess´?

Comment: Please show a full sample code plus the exact error message and line it occurs.

Comment: Use OracleCommand from the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client namespace instead of the System.Data.OracleClient namespace (check your usings).